# How to modify a Form and refresh it from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, public-method

I use two Forms:

Form1 contains button1

Form2 contains button2 and Panel1

My project starts using Form2. Then I click on button2 to show Form1

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 Frm = new Form1();
        Frm.Show();
    }
```

Then on Form1, I click on button1 to hide Panel1 on Form2

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 FormInstance = new Form2();
        FormInstance.displayInit();
        FormInstance.Refresh();
    }
```

displayInit() is a method inside Form2:

```
    public void displayInit()
    {
        panel1.Visible = false;
    }
```

But the panel is not hidden, due to a refresh issue, any idea please ?

Comment: Add `FormInstance.Show()` in button1_Click to see the new form you created.  There are many excellent books that help you learn object-oriented programming.

Comment: Thank you Hans, Is there a way to pass changes to the initially displayed Form2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of having two forms (or any two classes) talk to each other is with events.

In your case, add this to the top of the `Form1` code:

```
public event ClosePanelHandler ClosePanel;
public delegate void ClosePanelHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Then, in `Form1`'s Button1_Click event (this raises the event):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (ClosePanel != null){
       ClosePanel(this, new EventArgs());
    }}
```

-

Finally, `Form2` needs to handle the event (and be listening for it) in order to take action:

```
 private void HandleCloseRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     panel1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Also, modify

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 Frm = new Form1();
        Frm.ClosePanel += HandleCloseRequest;
        Frm.Show();
    }
```

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: @AlphaBird, You are welcome.  I made one slight change to `Form1`'s `button1_Click` event to check for `null`.  (If there are no listeners subscribed to the event, a `null` is returned which would throw an exception if we don't check for it.)